# Jenkins job fails on psexec -d

Tags: jenkins, psexec

I have a jenkins box, and a series of several hundred virtual machines.  We have a script that runs a set of tests against each machine using the psexec.

In order to speed up the runtime of the script, we have been using the -d flag, so that we don't wait for each command to complete before starting the next one in our loop.  I've confirmed that these tests were functional when run manually.

The trouble starts when I tried to use Jenkins to schedule this job.  I've been getting build failures.  Interestingly, when I investigated the virtual machines, I found that everything had been executed correctly.  After tooling around I removed the -d flag and, voila, the builds started passing.

Unfortunately, this is not a scalable project, and have these run in sequence withgout the -d flag is not viable.

I need to know if there is a way to get jenkins to work with psexec -d.  It seems as if the builds are failing because we reach the next step without receiving an expected response from psexec.  Is there a way I can fake this?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you need to run more than one psexec in the job?  This sounds like a case for a matrix job.

Comment: Yes, I can't post the code, but we've got a simple loop over a list of vms and we're using psexec to make some changes to each one of them.  Matrix jobs are new territory for me.

Comment: I'd look into matrix jobs. I don't have time just at the minute to post a full answer, but I might in an hour or two. But if you set up a single-axis job with the machines (or machine names) on the axis, then you should be able to run all the psexecs, one per job, at a much lower risk of Jenkins losing track of the async workings.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I'll start on the research.

Comment: Not sure this is going to solve the problem, although it does make sense for organizing the project as a whole.  I simplified the script to a one-line call of psexec -d on a single machine (no loop), and still failed, so even breaking it apart into a matrix organization seems like it would still break on the individual pieces.

Comment: Is it actually erroring, or just reporting a failure? Maybe change the Jenkins script to "exit 0" at the end, if the return code can be safely ignored. Jenkins reports a failure if the last command run in the batch exits with any code other than 0.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a fix,l but I'm open to other methods as mine seems to be less than ideal.

Since jenkins is waiting for a response from the batch script and psexec -d will not provide it in a timely manners, I've appended exit 0 to the end of the batch script.  This gives us a positive result on every execution and sllows me to perform my tasks.

Unfortunately I'm worried that it is also going to cover up other errors that would cause legitimate failures, so I'm going to have to break this down into multiple batch to isolate this masking effect.

Comment: Nice. I'll claim the moral victory on this :) You can display the real exit code in the job, then manually review the console output of the job everything now and then. However, it almost certainly won't tell you anything useful, since the real result isn't known until (long!) after psexec returns.  Instead, you should have a validation job check the real results every now and then. Possibly something like Nagios would help, or even some magic with Ansible or PowerShell DSC.